# malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted

Tags: c

This code generates an error at runtime in the else:

> non exists
>   *** Error in `./a.out': malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x09faed58 ***
>   Aborted (core dumped)

```
bool fileExists(char *file) {
    if (access(file, F_OK) != -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void CopyPaste() {
   char *fileName = basename(path);
   char *c = strcat(dest, "/");
   char *newPath = strcat(c, fileName);

   if (fileExists(newPath)) {
       printf("exists\n");
   } else {
       printf("non exists\n");
   }
}
```

If I change the concatenation code like that:

```
char *newPath = strcat(strcat(dest,"/"),fileName);
```

it generates this different error:

> Error in `./a.out': corrupted double-linked list

What might the problem be?

Comment: What is your work environment?

Comment: ubuntu, C program using gtk library

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i can't find the problem and solve it !!!!

Comment: `strcat` copies the second argument to the buffer given by the first.  `strcat(dest, "/")` and `strcat(strcat(dest, "/"), fileName);` look very suspicious. Where and how is `dest` defined? (BTW, you really should Google search "C formatting conventions" and follow some of the principles there. Your code is difficult to read.)

Comment: dest is a global variable it contains a path of destination (i get it from a gtk file schooser)

Comment: Please show exactly how you have it declared. Knowing it's a global variable and that it is supposed to contain something doesn't help. I'll emphasize again that `strcat` *modifies* the string at the location given by the first argument. So `dest` needs to hold the results in `strcat(dest, ...)`. `strcat` doesn't just concatenate into a newly allocated location. You need to read the manual page for `strcat`.

Comment: char *dest; dest = gtk_file_chooser_get_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));

Comment: `gtk_file_chooser_get_current_folder` returns a pointer to dynamically allocated memory that you must free with `g_free`.  You are copying in a string that is longer than the buffer and corrupting the heap.

Comment: Note that contrary to your assertion, the problem is *not* in your `else` block (either one).  I suppose you judge that because the output of that block is the last thing before the error message, but the problem is earlier, and the error message is probably generated later, by the C runtime library.

Comment: but i'm puting all in new variable newPath because i need dest

Comment: `newPath` and `dest` are both pointers that point to the same block of memory.

Comment: so where do you suggest me to free it and how?

Comment: You should free `dest` after its last use.  You must allocate a separate buffer large enough to hold the string you are trying to create.  You should copy `dest` into the larger buffer, append the slash filename, and then eventually call `g_free` with `dest`

Comment: Note that you can determine how much memory you string will require as `strlen(dest) + 1 + strlen(filename) + 1`.  You can `malloc` a buffer that size, and then `snprintf` the components into it.

Comment: Where does `path` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are not using `strcat` correctly. It appears that your code assumes the concatenation occurs into a new buffer internally allocated for you by `strcat` but that's not the case. `strcat` actually modifies the buffer pointed to by the first argument and appends the contents of the second buffer to the first.

Per the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html):

> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string,
>          **overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of `dest`**, and
>          then adds a terminating null byte.  The strings may not overlap, and
>          **the `dest` string must have enough space for the result.  If `dest` is
>          not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable;** buffer overruns
>          are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

In your case:

```
char *dest; dest =  gtk_file_chooser_get_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));
```

Will set `dest` per the return from `gtk_file_chooser_get_current_folder` which returns a buffer holding the folder name. That buffer **does not have extra space in it for you to append to it.** If you want to add (append) to the results of that function call, you need to allocate a separate buffer to hold that file name plus whatever you want to append.

```
char *new_dest = malloc(SIZE_YOU_NEED);

strcpy(new_dest, dest);   // Copy file name from gtk_file_chooser_get_current_folder
strcat(new_dest, "/");
strcat(new_dest, fileName);
```

And in this case, you could shortcut the last two lines as:

```
strcat(strcat(new_dest, "/"), fileName);
```

Since, according to the manual, `strcat` returns the first argument pointer back to you as a return value.

Comment: it works now , thank you so much, i didn't knew that strcat put te result in the first parametre

Comment: @Faceopace glad it works. That's why it's important to check the manual before using a function you haven't used before. They often don't work the way you think maybe they should. :)